# How to convert below java build.gradle to android build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, reportportal

Want to integrate reportPortal into my Espresso Automation. reportPortal have given below gradle configuration to add into main build.gradle of the project. Problem is, provided gradle is java based and my project is android based.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

description = 'ReportPortal JUnit 4 example'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.epam.reportportal:logger-java-log4j:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-junit:4.1.10'
}

ext {
    junitFoundation = configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.find { it.name == 'junit-foundation' }
}

test.doFirst {
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:${junitFoundation.file}"
}

test {
//  debug true
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

I have tried following things.

- I have removed below, because it asks for android plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

- I have upgraded the dependencies to

```
androidTestImplementation group: 'com.epam.reportportal', name: 'logger-java-log4j', version: '5.0.0-BETA-2'
androidTestImplementation group: 'com.epam.reportportal', name: 'agent-java-junit', version: '5.0.0-BETA-3'
```

- I converted `test` to `testOptions`.

But it is not working. Need help in fixing it.

Comment: Following link may help you. [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate#migrate_by_creating_a_custom_gradle_build_file)

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA, thanks but not much help.